# How to make 'onmouseout' event "understand", that the "span" height was increased?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code:

```html
<span id="one" onmouseover="AddString()" onmouseout="RemoveString()">First Line

  <span id="two" style="display:block"></span>

</span>

<script>

function AddString() {

    document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = 'Second Line';

}

function RemoveString() {

    document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = '';

}
</script>
```

If you hover mouse over the first line,then the second one appears. If you put mouse out of the first line (and do that slowly enough), then the second line disappears.

What do I need: after you have hovered over the first line and the second line has appeared, then the second line must disappear only if the cursor is outside the first OR second line. Which means, that if move mouse from the first line to the second line, the latter should not disappear. At the moment it does.

I have tried the following:

```html
<span id="one" onmouseover="AddString()">First Line

  <span id="two" style="display:block"></span>

</span>

<script>

function AddString() {

    var element = document.getElementById("one");

    element.removeEventListener("mouseover", AddString);

    document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = 'Second Line';
 
 element.addEventListener("mouseout", RemoveString, true);
 

}

function RemoveString() {

    var element = document.getElementById("two");

    element.removeEventListener("mouseout", RemoveString);

    element.innerHTML = '';
 
 element.addEventListener("mousever", AddString, true);

}
</script>
```

and was advised to do the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
   #one:hover+#two,#two:hover {
        display: block;
   }
   #two{
     display: none;
   }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
<span id="one">First Line</span>
<span id="two">Second Line</span>
</body>

</html>
```

No help. All those variants do not work. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your last example, just change the `<span>` tags to `<div>` tags and it works no problem.  Or if you want to keep them as `<span>` tags you can add `#one,#two { display:block; }` to your css to make them block items (so they will act like div tags anyway).
You can also limit the width of the div to ensure that it doesn't appear when you hover just anywhere on the line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
   #one,#two { width: 100px; background-color: beige; }
   #one:hover+#two,#two:hover {
        display: block;
   }
   #two{
     display: none;
   }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="one">First Line</div>
<div id="two">Second Line</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if I make them div or span with display block, then the AddString function will be activated, when I hover the mouse over the LINE along width the "First Line" string. But I need this to be activated, only when hovered above the "First Line" line.

Comment: You can add a width to your div such as this line of css - #one,#two { width: 100px; background-color: beige; } , this way it will not cover the whole line, just 100px or whatever you need, you can use a background-color to show the  area you can hover over